# Can a Raspberry Pi Zero support 640x480 just fine?

Tags: hdmi, screen

I almost never see anyone using a typical computer sized monitor for running Raspberry Pi Zeros. I usually only see those small LCD screens, given they're cheap, I'd like to be able to plug a Raspberry Pi Zero to my KVM so I can switch to it like I do for my 2 other computer.

The KVM is VGA, so I'll be using an active HDMI to VGA converter. The problem is I don't know if Raspberry Pi Zero can give the responsiveness you'd expect say for a digital media player (both for browsing through and playing media).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p

Comment: Define *just fine*. A simple Google search will tell you what the RPi is capable of in relatively detailed terms.

Answer (score 0):

All Pi models use identical Video Core and will support HD. I haven't seen a monitor limited to 640*480 for over 25 years.

If you are going to use a hdmi -> VGA converter performance will be mediocre, and the ability to power "active" converters can not be guaranteed.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi Zero will simply be limited to that resolution, as I thought the video performance of it was poor, at best. But, if you say all their video core is the same, then I guess it's as good as any official Raspberry Pi. I guess the wide usage of a small low res lcd screen threw me off. I'm viewing this on L1752TX, a fairly old, square lcd monitor.